# How to force Firefox to open downloads with new default file manager (Nemo)?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, firefox, filemanager, nemo

1. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.
2. Then I installed Nemo and configured it to be my new default file manager.

Most things works great, except for the browser Firefox. If I download a file and click in Firefox "**Open Containing Folder**", the browser will show the file with Nautilus and not with Nemo.

How to fix this?

My configuration to set Nemo to the default file manager:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

Output of `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`: `nemo.desktop`

The command `xdg-open $HOME` opens my home directory with Nemo.

**Update:**
This command does the trick:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nemo /usr/bin/nautilus
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/370119/179030

Comment: I replaced nautilus with nemo in /usr/share/applications/defaults.list and mimeinfo.cache but it still does not work

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/260249/179030

Comment: Thnx this solution worked for me! I will update my question.

Comment: This was fixed 4 years ago, but is an issue again with newer Firefox versions > v82. You'll need the dirty trick replacing the binary to make firefox work with nemo.

Comment: Just adding that nautilus might actually be called "Files" when you hit the "About" button. Took me a while to find out that this "Files" program *is* actually nautilus! (They write that only on their webpage, which you get using the "Help" button, I think. So it's really well hidden...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nemo /usr/bin/nautilus
```

Comment: Also helps with Dropbox!

Comment: That shouldn't be a valid solution. That's just a dirty trick to make nemo as nautilus.

Comment: This doesn't work in ubuntu 22.04 anymore, since firefox was put in a snap.

Answer (score 4):

This is an awkward, quick and dirty solution you advocate. You Can't use `Nautilus` anymore. If it's your intention then it's better to remove it for good.

`$ sudo apt-get remove nautilus`

Otherwise I believe the proper solution is to modify the `defaults.list` file located in `/usr/share/applications` as suggested [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager).

In Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 I did comment out the original line and replaced `nautilus` with `nemo` e.g.

```
#inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
inode/directory=nemo.desktop
```

Then just restart Firefox and you will be OK ...

Comment: This is of course valid if you previously set `Nemo` as default modifying the gsettings. Instructions are widely available on `webupd8.com`, `noobslab.com` etc ...

Answer (score -1):

Run the below command and check in which app the folder belongs too,

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

After doing so inorder to set nemo as your default try the below,

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

In order to check whether nemo has set as default use the below,

```
xdg-open $HOME
```

Comment: Sry, this does not solve the problem.
My default file manager is already Nemo. Output of `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`: `nemo.desktop`. Firefox still opens the download folder with Nautilus.